# Changing rounded numbers to equal their sum

Tags: excel, vba

In our financial statements we round everything to whole numbers and then sum them.  Of course, the actual sum of the individual numbers does not always equal the summation of these numbers.  I understand the reasons for this happening, but I want the rounded summation of the actual numbers to print and the component numbers to be "fudged" so that they equal the total.  For example, if I have the numbers 5.20, 4.30, and 6.40 they are going to sum to 15.90.  If I round them to a whole number I will obtain 5,4,and 6 and they will sum to 15.  What I want is for the total to be 16 (the rounded summation of all of the component items) and the individual numbers to round to 5, 4, and 7 (fudged from 6.)  Is there a way to accomplish this?  Of course, my financial statements have thousands of numbers on them so I need some sort of formula that will work on all of them.

I have searched the Internet but can find nothing on this topic.

Thank you!

Comment: You really shouldn't round your numbers before the arithmetic, do all your math then round your final numbers.  I can't think of a way of doing what you want otherwise.

Comment: If you decrease the decimal then you won't have to round anything manually. In a cell with decreased decimals, you would still type `5.20`, `4.30`, `6.40`, and it will only show `5`,`4`, & `6` respectively - but will still store their actual values.

Comment: It's not impossible, but if you have 'thousands of numbers' then you've got another issue. You could end up with a modifier (as you call it - the fudge) that is much larger than the number it's modifying. Are you sure you want that? Or do you want the 'fudge' spread over as many entries as required, never altering them by more than 1?

Comment: Yes, CLR, that is exactly what I want to do.  Can it be done?  Thank you!

Comment: @FloridaRick, due to your later comment as of 16/1 2018 I added a second approach -> see **II. Nearest Roundings** in an edit. This fast array filtering method should meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**VBA approach without using any helper column**

- Based on @CLR 's *'fudging' method* +, I show you a **fast VBA approach** via datafield array allowing you to forget about any helper columns.
- Due to a later comment I edited a second approach => *see **II. Nearest roundings***

> **I. First approach (based on CLR's method)**

In my example I assume you have values in cells `B2:B{n}` including a *last row* with a *total sum formula*. In *section (b)* I create a one based 2-dim array, do some subsequent calculations and in *section (g)* I write the (redimmed) array `v` back to the same column B, but you can easily change that to any wanted column.

**Method**

The *program logic* is based on calculating the difference between i.) the rounded total sum and ii.) the sum of each individual rounding and a subsequent value correction. Roundings are effectuated to whole numbers via `WorksheetFunction.Round()` (as opposed to so called *Banker's Rounding* via VBA's `Round` function)

**Code**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Fudge()
  Dim v     As Variant
  Dim i     As Long, n As Long
  Dim total As Double, rounded As Double, diff As Double
  Dim d     As Double, m As Double
  Dim ws    As Worksheet, Rng As Range
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")   ' << change to your sheet name
' (a) get last row in column B containing data  '    (omitting last row with total sum!)
      n = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row - 1 ' << subtract 1 if last sum row!
' (b) get values (col.B-data, col.C- for calculation) to one based 2dim array
      v = ws.Range("B2:C" & n).Value
' (c) loop through array to round (items count n - 1, as omitting one title row!)
      For i = 1 To n - 1
          v(i, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Round(v(i, 1), 0)
      Next i
' (d) calculate difference to sum of rounded values
      Set Rng = ws.Range("B2:B" & n)            '
      total = Application.Sum(Rng)
      rounded = Application.Sum(Application.Index(v, 0, 2))
      diff = WorksheetFunction.Round(total - rounded, 0)
      ' Debug.Print "Fudge Difference = WorksheetFunction.Round(" & total & " - " & rounded & ", 0) = " & Format(diff, "0.00;-0.00")
' (e) Loop through array and "fudge" (items count n - 1, as omitting one title row!)
      For i = 1 To n - 1
        ' get modifier
          m = IIf(d < diff, 1, 0)
        ' "fudge" values and cumulate modifiers
          v(i, 1) = v(i, 2) + m: d = d + m
      Next i
' (f) redim to one column only (items count n - 1, as omitting title row)
      ReDim Preserve v(1 To n - 1, 1 To 1)
' (g) write back to B (or to ANY wanted column :-)
      ws.Range("B2:B" & n).Value = v
End Sub
```

> **===== EDIT 1/17 2018 =======**

**II. Nearest roundings (cf. comment as of 16/1 2018)**

This should meet your latest requirements to

> "..change the items that rounded to $0.50 from the actual amount FIRST, then change the items that rounded off to either $0.51 or $0.49 from the actual amount, then those that round to $0.52 or $0.48, etc, etc. No number should be rounded by more than $0.99."

**Method**

The Program logic also calculates the difference between i.) the rounded total sum and ii.) the sum of each individual rounding, but uses a refined correction pattern.

Basically this 2nd approach uses a datafield array combined with some filtering methods based on a loop through the nearest absolute differences around $0.50 and a search for a special alphnumeric code combining these 50 differences with the item number.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit
Sub Fudge()
  Dim s As String
  Dim v, vx     As Variant
  Dim ii  As Long
  Dim total As Double, rounded As Double, diff As Double, diffrest As Double, cent As Double
  Dim i     As Long, j As Long, n As Long
  Dim ws    As Worksheet
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet")   ' << change to your sheet name
' --------------------------------------------------------------------
' I.  Get data for normal roundings and code absolute cent differences
' --------------------------------------------------------------------
' (a) get last row in column B containing data  '    (omitting last row with total sum!)
      n = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row - 1 ' << subtract 1 if last sum row!
' (b) get values (col.B-data, col.C-D temp) to one based 2dim array
      v = ws.Range("B2:D" & n).Value
      total = Application.Sum(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(v, 0, 1)))
' (c) loop through array to round (items count n - 1, as omitting one title row!)
      For i = 1 To n - 1
        ' round original values
          v(i, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Round(v(i, 1), 0)
        ' convert absolute cent differences 1-100 to chr codes and add item no
          v(i, 3) = Chr(64 + (0.51 - Abs(v(i, 2) - v(i, 1))) * 100) & _
                    Format(i, "0")   ' << corr./edited
        ' overwrite original data in col2 with rounded values col1, AFTER coding!
          v(i, 1) = v(i, 2)
      Next i
' --------------------------------------------------------------------
' II. Calculate 'fudge'
' --------------------------------------------------------------------
      rounded = Application.Sum(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(v, 0, 2)))
      diff = WorksheetFunction.Round(rounded - total, 0)    ' resting difference
      diffrest = diff
' --------------------------------------------------------------------
' III. 'Fudge' resting difference using Filter function
' --------------------------------------------------------------------
  For j = 0 To 49                      ' absolute cent differences 0 to 49
      If diffrest = 0 Then Exit For    ' escape if no diffrest left
      s = Chr(64 + j)                  ' code differences from Chr(64)="A" to Chr(64+49)="q"
  '  (a) get zerobased 1-dim array via ' Filter function
      vx = Filter(Application.Transpose(Application.Index(v, 0, 3)), s)
  '  (b) Adapt roundings nearest to .50, .49, to .99 cents (i.e. j = 0, 1 to 49)
      For i = LBound(vx) To UBound(vx) ' loop through filter items
           ii = Val("0" & Replace(vx(i), s, "")) ' get coded Item index from filter array
           If ii <> 0 Then
              If diffrest <> 0 Then    ' remaining diffrest
                 cent = IIf(diffrest > 0, -1, 1) ' get fudge cent
                 v(ii, 1) = v(ii, 2) + cent      ' << new value = rounded +/- 1 cent
                 diffrest = WorksheetFunction.Round(diffrest + cent, 0)
               ' check escape condition: no remaining diffRest
                 If diffrest = 0 Then Exit For
               End If
           End If
      Next i
  Next j
' --------------------------------------------------------------------
' IV. Write results
' --------------------------------------------------------------------
' (a) redim to one column only (items count n - 1, as omitting title row)
      ReDim Preserve v(1 To n - 1, 1 To 1)
' (b) write back to B (or to ANY wanted column :-)
      ws.Range("C2:C" & n).Value = v
End Sub
```

**Note**

Explications are added to the above code as comments. I assume that code starts in the second row (omitting the title row) and that there is a last row with a possible total sum or formula which is omitted, too.

> **Edit 1/22 2018 - Debug indicated code line**

Due to your comment as of 22/1 try the following by inserting some Error handling in your **I.c) loop**:

```
    ' convert ...
      On Error Resume Next                                                       ' << EDIT 1/22 2018
      v(i, 3) = Chr(64 + (0.51 - Abs(v(i, 2) - v(i, 1))) * 100) & Format(i, "0") ' << code line in question
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then                                                    ' << EDIT 1/22 2018
         Debug.Print "Error No " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
         Debug.Print "i =" & i
         Debug.Print "v(" & i & ",1)=" & v(i, 1), "v(" & i & ",2)=" & v(i, 2)
         Debug.Print (0.51 - Abs(v(i, 2) - v(i, 1))) * 100
         v(i, 3) = 0
         Err.Clear
      End If
    ' overwrite ...
```

Comment: Thank you both!  I was gone for the long holiday weekend so I am just now reading your solutions.  Today is going to be rather hectic so I am hoping to test both approaches over the next few days to see which one meets my needs better.  I will get back to you soon.  Again, thanks to both of you!

Comment: I couldn't wait to evaluate these solutions so I am putting off my other work until later.  Unfortunately, neither solution does what I wanted it to do.  I am afraid I was not clear with CLR.  When I said that is exactly what I wanted to do, I was referring to his/her solution "Or do you want the 'fudge' spread over as many entries as required, never altering them by more than 1? "  I apologize for the unclear answer.

Comment: TM is on the correct track, but his/her solution makes all of the changes in the first 22 rows of an 872 row column in which the rounded values are $21.00 different from the actual values.  What I wanted was for it to change the items that rounded to $0.50 from the actual amount FIRST, then change the items that rounded off to either $0.51 or $0.49 from the actual amount, then those that round to $0.52 or $0.48, etc, etc.  No number should be rounded by more than $0.99.  Is that possible?  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, will have a look till tomorrow. The basic advantage of this approach is to be very fast.

Comment: I tried to run the macro, but it keeps hanging up on the Format command in I.(c).  I get the error message: "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment."  How do I fix this?  Also, I REALLY appreciate the comments you have added!  They make things much easier to understand for a beginner such as myself!

Comment: a) At which code line precisely does code sto`p? Move your mouse over variable i - which value do you see? - Please tell me (b) You could also try to debug your code by inserting a `Stop` Statement before the loop in *I.c*, and check variables directly in the immediate window (`Crtl+G`) of your VBA Editor (VBE) by typing e.g. `? i` plus *Enter key* to get the last value of e.g. variable `i`, press `F8` to continue code or end the whole test by clicking at the blue square button on top of VBE or `F5` (cf http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: The line says Format (I, 0).  It is 3 code lines ABOVE II. Calculate 'fudge'.  I don't see anything when I hover over anything on the screen.  I am in the debugger screen.  VBA will not allow me to do anything else until I fix that Compile Error.

Comment: I think you have overseen the special `_` character followed by a line break, that indicates that this represents *one logically* **connected statement** (look at my original code); instead of this form of representation you can connect both lines to: `v(i, 3) = Chr(64 + (0.51 - Abs(v(i, 2) - v(i, 1))) * 100) & Format(i, 0)`.

Comment: I removed the _ and cut and pasted the Format (I, 0) so that it looks like yours.  I then checked the entire line, character-by-character, and it is identical.  I still get the box that says Compile Error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.  The word Format is highlighted in blue.  Any ideas?

Comment: Format (I, 0) is actually Format (i, 0)

Comment: Of course it should be `Format(i, "0")` with a string as number pattern; to my surprise this incorrect Syntax did run in my Excel 2010 Pro (Win 7) without problems.

Comment: I changed the 0 to "0" and tried to run it again, but I got the same message.  It still doesn't like something about that Format command.  I can't step through the macro because it is a compile error.  I am using Excel 2013 if that makes a difference.  Thank you!

Comment: Please communicate me your first numbers in column B2:B?)  as well as the info line indicated in your immediate window (Ctrl+G) when you insert a `Debug.Print i, n, v(i,1), v(i, 2)` before the comment `'  convert ...` followed by the cited code line with `Format`.

Comment: The first three numbers are: 2,019.00, 192,397.38, and 1,648.48.  If you need more, just let me know.  Nothing appeared in the window and I received the same error message as before.  If you can tell me how to do it, I will send a screen shot to you.

Comment: You can upload an image of your VBA Editor window. Edit your post and press Ctrl+G somewhere in your edit window. - Maybe you should try to copy the whole code once again to your code module - I suppose a **typo** -  and execute a `Stop` in the code lines + F8 to continue (cf  cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: I tried copying the whole thing again with no better results.

Comment: I cannot use stops or step into the code because as soon as I touch the Run or Step Into key, the macro goes straight to the Compiler Error message.  I tried the Ctrl-G thing, but it did not put anything into this window as I had expected.  In case you haven't guessed, I am REALLY new to this stuff!  Perhaps you could provide the instructions in greater detail and then I could do it?  Thank you so much for all of your efforts.  I do appreciate them!

Comment: @FloridaRick, added some Debugging.info to my answer (see Edit 22/1). Please insert `On Error Resume Next` immediately before the code line in question and the indicated lines below it. Do you get any result in the immediate Window (Ctrl+G)?

Comment: You have to be in the Visual Basic Editor (VBE) by selecting *Tools > Macro > Visual Basic Editor*, there you can press the Ctrl+G key to see the immediate window and see results after having inserted the proposed code lines.

Comment: Nothing appears in the Immediate Window and I am getting the same error message.

Comment: I can't find an error and it is not possible for me to simulate a situation that raises Error 450 "Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment" for me. You could try to ask this as a new question (repeating the full code and link) with the hint to an Error 450 occurring in Excel 2013 and not in Excel 2010.

Comment: OK.  Thank you for all of your efforts!  I truly appreciate them!

Comment: You are welcome; saw your follow up question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48423691/force-rounding-to-equal-the-sum and am hoping for a solution, as code is running on other computers, too. (cf. SRJ 's suggestions in comment).

Comment: The problem has been solved thx to @SJR 's hint by assigning the worksheet object to a workbook containing the referred sheet, e.g. `Set ws = Workbooks("FudgeRoundings.xlsm").Worksheets("MySheet")` instead of `ThisWorkbook` as Florida had the macro coded in the **Personal macro library** and not in the referred code module of her workbook.

Comment: Yes!!!   It solved a very big problem for me!  Before, I spent the better part of an entire day rounding and unrounding amounts.  Now, a click of a button does it!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have column A with a header and then your values - `5.20`, `4.30` and `6.40`.

In column B you have a formula that rounds the column A value - `=ROUND(A2,0)`, `=ROUND(A3,0)` and `=ROUND(A4,0)`

You'd then want a modifier column containing the following formula IN CELL C2:

`=IF(SUM(C$1:C1)<ROUND(SUM(A:A),0)-SUM(B:B),1,0)`

Copy the above down, and you'll see an additional `1` appear in each cell until it makes up the difference between the column A total and the rounded column B total.

Finally, a final column (D) to add B and C together will give you your required values. I've added another item but it might look something like this:

[image: screengrab of demo]